# Invalid base64 string from canvas

Tags: php, javascript, html, canvas, base64

I'm making a web application that'll be used on an iPad. Users will be invited to color an image. I'm using html5 Canvas for this and basing  the coloring on the [tutorial I found HERE](http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-drawing-app/). Eventually I want to upload this image to a Database along with the name of the user.

### How I'm doing it

When the user is done coloring he hits 'save' and I convert the canvas using toDataURL(). I then insert the data into an invisible form element and submit the form to go to a new page. Like so:

```
    document.getElementById('my_hidden').value = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    document.forms["form1"].submit();
```

Here I ask the user's name and e-mail. I also insert the canvas data into a new invisible form element. Like so:

```
    value="<?php echo $_POST['my_hidden'];?>"
```

I then submit this form to the database on the next php page. The canvas data is stored in a Blob.

This all works fine.

### What's going wrong

When I try to display the image on that final page I get a 'Failed to load resource'-error on the image ('kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error'). I'm trying to display it this way:

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var image = new Image();

    image.src = "<?php echo str_replace("\n", "", $_POST['canvas']); ?>";
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
```

Now I suspected that maybe the canvas data I got from the sever is bad. So I checked it this way:

```
    if ( base64_encode(base64_decode($canvas)) === $canvas){
       echo '$data is valid';
    } else {
       echo '$data is NOT valid';
    }
```

And it is, indeed, not valid. I then used that same method to check it after the first form and it's already invalid then. So I suppose either the first submitting through that hidden field is messing it up or the toDataURL() is.

I'm by no means an expert programmer but I'd hate to get this far and not finish this. So any help would be truly, greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you're forgetting to snip off the start of the data URI to leave yourself with just the data

```
var uri = canvas.toDataURL('image/png'),   // data:image/png;base64,blahblahblah
    b64 = uri.slice(uri.indexOf(',') + 1); // blahblahblah
document.getElementById('my_hidden').value = b64;
```

Comment: Jup, that fixed the broken base64 string error! But now I'm getting an HTTP request error 414 because the URI is so long. Any suggestions on how to avoid this? Thanks already!

Comment: At what stage is the `414` error happening? if it is the line `image.src = // ...`, are you adding in the dataURI bits back in again? Not doing this means it will think you're after a file on the server. If it is happening on the upload stage, consider uploading by a different method

Comment: I see. I didn't add it back in again. I tried this and now the error is gone but still no image. Think I might have to look for another approach indeed...


    `image.src = "<?php 
      $base = "data:image/png;base64,";
      $drawing= $_POST['canvas'];
      $combined = $base.$other;
      echo $combined; ?>";
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);`